# Rearrange style properties in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio allows to easily order properties of the views in XML files (`layout_width`, `style`, `id`, etc.) with a simple shortcut `CTRL + ALT + L`

However I could not find a way to arrange those same properties within style declarations. Is that possible in any way?

Edit: [Corresponding issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230223&thanks=230223&ts=1481709935) for starring if not possible